# Google Chrome shortcut all disabled?

Tags: google-chrome, mac, shortcuts

I'm using a google chrome browser on a mac sonoma 14.1.2.
Today, suddenly most keyboard shortcuts failed to work: I can't copy using cmd+c, nor paste (cmd+v) or find (cmd+f). Although cmd+left still works.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Somehow it automatically fixed. Guess Chrome's team fixed them?